# This question already has answers... where?

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions

For this question: [if/else statements or exceptions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141522/if-else-statements-or-exceptions)

[image]

I feel like the "Possible Duplicate" text should not be there, and the "Defensive Programming vs Exception Handling?" question link should appear under the "This question already has answers here:" text.

Answer (score 6):

That's because that question has been closed a long, long time ago, when the duplicate notice was added *in the question body itself*. It needs a ♦ moderator (or a gold tag badge holder, but there are none in the question's tags) to reopen and close the question again; then, the blue notice will be updated and show the correct duplicate.

Reference: [Duplicate post notice missing the duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338534/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it. Thanks for pointing it out.